# Why is not Qt label refreshed?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

This is a method that I call from a button click

```
void ChangeLabelText(QLabel* myLabel)
{
    int countNumber = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)//outer loop
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 65000; k++)//inner loop
        {
            countNumber++;
        }
        myLabel->setText(QString::number(countNumber));
    }
}
```

When the code runs text of the label is set at the end of the `outer loop`, but I expected it to set label's text every time `inner loop` finishes. What might be causing it?

Comment: Your code executed in the main thread and in the main thread th UI update happens on events callbacks. What you need is to force repaint your ui. You can do it by calling `repaint()` or by asking aplication to process events `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`. You need to make it after changing label.

Comment: The text is set each time through the loop - but the label is not repainted until the execution returns to the event loop and the paint event can be processed. If controls were repainted in real time as their properties changed, you'd see an awful lot of flicker.

Comment: @johngull  Your answer worked perfectly. You can enter it as answer so that amateur people like me can see the answer.

Comment: You can try `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myLabel, "setText", Q_ARG(QString, QString::number(countNumber)), Qt::QueuedConnection); QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myLabel, "repaint", Qt::QueuedConnection);` instead of the direct setText call. That will cause high event traffic, but should work aswell

Answer (score 1):

Your code executed in the main thread and in the main thread th UI update happens on events callbacks. What you need is to force repaint your ui. You can do it by calling `repaint()` or by asking aplication to process events with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`. You need to make it after changing label.